# ANDROID-Failed to allocate memory: 1455

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm a beginner of android development, just had the SDK and AVD stuffs installed in my eclipse and started with a [simple "Hello World" example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

But i had the following error on Run...**(RAM-256mb)**

`[2011-11-11 20:42:02 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Venkat'
[2011-11-11 20:42:31 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
[2011-11-11 20:42:31 - Emulator] 
[2011-11-11 20:42:31 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-11-11 20:42:31 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.`

Answer (score 7):

Open Android Virtual Device Manager and add or change the value to device ram size to 15 or a value smaller or higher, in hardware section.

Answer (score 2):

I have the best and right solution proved according to the indications by Calvin in techarena forums.

- Click Start, click Run, type sysdm.cpl in the Open box, and then press ENTER.
- Click the Advanced tab, and then under Performance click Settings.
- Click the Advanced tab, and then under Virtual memory click Change.
- Under Drive [Volume Label], click the drive that contains the paging file that you want to change.
- Under Paging file size for selected drive, click Custom size, type a new paging file size in megabytes (MB) in the Initial size (MB) or Maximum size (MB) box, and then click Set.
- Click OK to close the dialog box and apply changes.

This usual error "Failed to allocate memory: 1455" would be caused by Virtual Memory alocation. After resolving in this way the allocation of Virtual Memory for the root C disk, you should read in the console of Eclipse, the following:

> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] ------------------------------
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Android Launch!
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] adb is running normally.
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Performing 
>   com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1.Videotutorial1Activity activity launch
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'VtAVD' is not available. Launching new emulator.
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'VtAVD'
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:39 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:39 - Emulator]
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:45 - Videotutorial1] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>
> [2011-11-27 12:33:45 - Videotutorial1] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>
> [2011-11-27 12:38:19 - Videotutorial1] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
>
> [2011-11-27 12:38:19 - Videotutorial1] Uploading Videotutorial1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>
> [2011-11-27 12:38:20 - Videotutorial1] Installing Videotutorial1.apk...
>
> [2011-11-27 12:40:52 - Videotutorial1] Success!
>
> [2011-11-27 12:40:53 - Videotutorial1] Starting activity com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1.Videotutorial1Activity on device emulator-5554
>
> [2011-11-27 12:41:18 - Videotutorial1] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1' on port 8628

Comment: My box has 4gb memory, but I had the page file turned off.  I turned it back on and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Virtual Device settings and change the RAM allocation to a lower/higher number.

Take a look at [Android Development Guide](http://droidsquad.blogspot.com/)

Comment: hi, thanks,, but when i checked it out and changed my RAM to 256, again said the same error.. i even tried reducing it a little to 190 (same error)..

Comment: your android platform is 4 or 3.x ? check whether you have allocated less RAM to it?

Comment: 4.0 API Level-14,, yaa,, ive set it to 190mb,, its just an "hello world" demo app,, and i think i've met the system requirements to run that demo app,, but i need some technical assistance if im doing the right thing,,??

Comment: This problem is surely for memory(RAM) allocation.Try increasing RAM (like 512).I had also experienced this but in my case it solved when i installed avd 3.2

Answer (score 1):

An even easier solution for this problem is just **deleting** in the Android Virtual Device Manager **the device that has this problem**. 
Just create another one that is exactly the same and all is ready to go.

I followed the solution by Jayesh but I still was having this problem, my recomendation does not include the restart of the PC and the hazzle of modifying virtual paging in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Im a beginner also - try creating a new Virtual Device, and select 768 RAM and Snapshot. But when you start the device the first time - select Save to Snapshot, but unselect Launch from Snapshot. I had the same problem as you and this seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using  windows 10.Same problem i was faced in Android studio.I got following errors

- adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
  console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
- Failed to alloc 8388608 bytes for ReadBuffer.

I solved by delete my old AVD and  create new AVD by click **create Virtual Device button** select

> Nexus 5 API 21    1080 × 1920: xxhdpi 21  Android 5.0.1   x86

and click **pencil** icon and click  **Show Adv Settings** button to change the memory and storage values like 
[RAM size 562 and VM size greater than 364](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32a0.png) then click finish. close AVD Manager Window. Now new AVD updated. Again goto **AVD Manager window** and  launch the new AVD emulator.. :) Please wait few minitutes.. I hope its help you.. please check all the steps before basic package Installation in
[SDK manager] and intelhaxm-android.exe installation. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj7Qi.png)